# How to add more than one custom css file into R markdown file?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Can I add more than one custom css file into R Markdown file?

I found that, add the following code in the head, I can add a customer css file.

```
html_document: 
  css: /css/my1.css
```

But this method just allowed one css file. Is it possible add more than one customer css file into a Rmd file?

Answer (score 2):

By poring through the sources I eventually figured out that the `output` portion of the Rmd headers can be specified as an R function.  Here is a header I use as part of my `diffobj` package to get two CSS files in:

```
---
title: "diffobj - Diffs for R Objects"
author: "Brodie Gaslam"
output:
    function(...) rmarkdown::html_vignette(..., md_extensions="-markdown_in_html_blocks", css=c(file.path(system.file(package="diffobj"), "css", "diffobj.css"), "styles.css")):
        toc: true

vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{diffobj}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

---
```

You can skip the `md_extensions` part for your purposes.  The key is what happens with the `css` argument.  With that argument I specify the following two files:

- `file.path(system.file(package="diffobj"), "css", "diffobj.css")`, from my package
- `"styles.css"`, in the same folder as the vignette Rmd

The above is in the context of using `devtools::build_vignettes()`, but I imagine you can use a similar solution in your situation.